# Brake grinding noise audible at low speeds after strut replacement

Tags: brakes, mazda, mazda-3

My brakes are fairly new, about 1 year old and about 80% left

I had my struts replaced for my Mazda 3. When I drove after that it made a lot of grinding noise which was audible at low speeds. I went back to the mechanic and he blamed the rotors. He machined those which reduced the noise for a day or two.

Now there is again a lot of noise and the mechanic wants me to change the rotors and pads with no guarantee of fixing the issue.

Could someone suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe a bad wheel bearing?

Comment: Does the noise change any by applying the brakes?

Comment: Yes , as soon as I apply brakes , a grinding noise comes.